# Assigning a value to a [string] / [item in list]

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

I am creating a card game - *blackjack* - and need to display a string to the user, but keep track of the points that each card is worth for the calculations. So, I created a list with all the values of a card:

```
cards = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,...]
```

But to the user, for example I want to display `King` if the item in the list is `13`. How would I make a dictionary / key or an **array** containing these values? I cannot use a dictionary based on position, as once the card is dealt, I will remove it from the `list` / `deck`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, you can represent the cards as their values. The aces as 1, the kings as 13, etc...

You can construct your "deck" just as you'd expect. A list of [1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,...] and manipulate that however you want.

To actually display the card to the user, use the cardnames list Willem mentioned. This will work since the card value 1 will correspond to the card name in the first (zeroth) position of the cardnames list: "Ace".

For example:

```
Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 10 2014, 17:10:18) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cardnames = ["Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
>>> hand = [1,1,2,4,6,3,11,8]
>>> for x in hand:
...  print(cardnames[x-1])
... 
Ace
Ace
2
4
6
3
Jack
8
```

Comment: I am not completely understanding. What if the player's hand is `[2,2,6,12]`? or has 2 + of the same card. I feel like I need a dictionary because after the card is **used**, I will **remove** it out of the deck.

Comment: My new edit should help explain things. Essentially, you keep your name list and your card list separate. You can shuffle or otherwise edit your card list, but your name list should be static.

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You simply define a list of strings:

```
cardnames = ["Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
```

Now if the card has value `v`, you can get the corresponding name with `cardnames[v-1]`. For instance:

```
v = 5
print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
```

In that case the value for the jack is 11, for Queen 12 and for King 13. For instance (using `python`'s interactive shell):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cardnames = ["Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
>>> v=12
>>> print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
I have a Queen
>>> v=7
>>> print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
I have a 7
>>> v=1
>>> print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
I have a Ace
>>> v=13
>>> print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
I have a King
```

Or using `python3`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:03:40) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cardnames = ["Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
>>> v=12
>>> print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
I have a Queen
>>> v=7
>>> print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
I have a 7
>>> v=1
>>> print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
I have a Ace
>>> v=13
>>> print("I have a %s"%cardnames[v-1])
I have a King
```

Comment: So basically you are finding what position the string is in? Also, why would you do `[v-1]` instead of `[v+1]`

Comment: Because numbering with lists start at `0`. The value of your card system seems to start at `1`. In order to map `1` to `0`, `2` to `1`, etc. you can subtract with `1`..

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I need python3 *`3.4`*, not python2.

Comment: That's not a problem. You can fully reproduce the example using Python 3.4.

Comment: Thanks! 2 more things. 1. **I need `4` of each card**, not 1. So how would I find the position of the cards, using that? Also, **I am going to _shuffle_** the list, so position wouldn't really work well.

Comment: @retep: Tag values with their index before doing so. `enumerate` will probably be useful here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger would this work?  `for x,y in enumerate(cards):`

Comment: @retep: Yes, though it's just iterating with index and value; you'd have to do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary for the translation from number to card name.  Like this:

```
faces = {
    1: 'Ace',
    2: '2',
    3: '3',
    ...
    11: 'Jack',
    12: 'Queen',
    13: 'King'
}
```

Then, you can call them accordingly.  Like:

```
faces[cardnames[13]]
```

would equal "King"

To elaborate a bit, since there were question in the comments:

a dict (which is what faces is) is a set of key value pairs. In this case, the "key" is the numeric value of the card and the "value" is the face (string) of the card. You reference a value from a dict by it's key.

For example.   If I have a dict like the one above, and I say:

```
faces[1]
```

And that would be 'Ace'.  For example:

```
>>> faces = {1: 'Ace', 11: 'Jack', 12: 'Queen', 13: 'King'}
>>> faces[1]
'Ace'
>>> faces[13]
'King'
>>> cards = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,11]
>>> cards[1]
1
>>> faces[cards[1]]
'Ace'
```

Comment: Why is `cardnames` in there?

Comment: @retep - That's your list of card values that you referenced in your question.  I didn't know what the rest of your code looks like, so I assumed you needed to reference that list.   So, a dict (which is what faces is) is a set of key value pairs.  In this case, the "key" is the numeric value of the card and the "value" is the face (string) of the card.  You reference a value from a dict by it's key.